# Any official presentation about the difference for launcher between platform 1.6 and 2.1?

Tags: android, launcher

Is there any official presentation about the difference for launcher between platform 1.6 and 2.1?
I wanna port some features to my launcher application based on 1.6 from 2.1. But it seems few difference between 1.6 and 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such official presentation sorry. There wasn't much different about it except for the live wallpapers support and various aesthetics changes.

Comment: Thanks! I have the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the differences are: 1. bug fixing, unused code deletion, unused resources deletion, resources replacement and translation revision; 2. Quick Contact for favorites; 3. Able to preinstall uri shortcuts; 3. New wallpaper API, the launcher is transparent; 4. Live wallpaper support.